# How to Quit Flower Dashboard for Celery

Tags: celery

I started a flower dashboard and I can't figure out how to stop it. I killed the screen session running the dashboard but it's still going. I can't find anything in the documentation about stopping the dashboard itself, only using the dashboard to stop celery workers.

Is there an easy way to stop the dashboard or do I have to go through every running process to find it?